# string to picture - python

Tags: python, image

Is there a way I can converts a string into an image?
For example the string "aaaa" will be converted to [image]

I've tried to use some CAPTCHA generator in python with no success.

Purpose - I want to check if a string contains **English** alphabet letters (in visual aspect). I will convert it to image and then convert it back to string using OCR.

For example the following image [image: c]ontains two Cyrillic letters (not English) that were converted from a string to image. Using this method I can recognize if Cyrillic letters that looks like English letters.

Regular English alphabet match won't work here.

Comment: The [Pillow](https://python-pillow.org/) library can draw text on an image.

Comment: Thanks, its really useful. 
Now I need the other side - image to string (OCR). I've tried multiple vectors, all of them failed. Is there a specific way you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cairo graphics, the gtk low level renderer would be a good choice. Basically, you instantiate a Cairo object, set the text properties, write the text and save the image:

https://github.com/pygobject/pycairo/blob/master/examples/cairo_snippets/snippets/text.py

https://pycairo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html